# What's the recommended storage for a dictionary on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, data-structures

For a dictionary of about 100,000 words between 2 languages, what's the recommended storage, .plist, sqlite, Core Data?

I am looking for performance of looking up a word within one second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data and sqlite will both give lookup times far under one second (or even 0.1 seconds).   If you have a lot of experience with SQL sqlite might be simpler for you to use, otherwise Core Data will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is the iOS API for SQLite. It simplifies much of SQLite programming. That would definitely be your best bet for storage of such a large amount of data, and for easy access to it. If you are a registered Apple Developer, [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405); is a great sample project for Core Data, that implements NSFetchedResultsController for fetching data as well. As well, [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) is the first of a great three part tutorial on Core Data, that goes a long way towards explaining how the different parts work.

Comment: Core Data is not just an API for SQlite. Core Data is much much much much more. But still, Core Data is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write cross platform code, use SQLite3 through its C API. If you are only targeting iOS (and don't plan to expand), then CoreData does give you a lot more.